# List Comprehension multiple values/keys

Tags: python

I need some advice on the following code. I need to be able to extract two pieces of information but I need them in the same variable, for example,

```
  item_out_list = [{
    "fvRsNodeAtt": {
        "attributes": {
            "annotation": "",
            "childAction": "",
            "descr": "apple",
            "value": "mango"
    
        }
    }
},
{"fvRsNodeAtt": {
        "attributes": {
            "annotation": "",
            "childAction": "",
            "descr": "peach",
            "value": "banana"
    
        }
    }
}
]
```

```
  static = [item['fvRsNodeAtt']['attributes']['descr'] for item in item_out_list]
  print(static)
```

So the above gives me the value Apple, which is great but what I want to do is also grab "value" at the same time. I know could run another list and grab the value separate but I need them on same line, so when I print it out, I see apple mango.

I could join them together easily but I thought they might be an easier or efficient way of accessing the extra keys because it might be that I need 3 or 4 keys from the json above as it grows, for example, "annotation", "childAction", "descr", etc.

So the item_out_list is coming from a REST API, so there is multiple entries every time.

So when I lookup the values I want, it might be

apple mango
peach apple
banana orange.

so every time I query the API, I will get a different response, I am then using List comp to pull that out and save to CSV. The CSV isnt the problem, I just need to access more then one value and save to a variable

any help would be great

Comment: Can you share an example of the output you're trying to get? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Why is `item_out_list` a dictionary?

Comment: since there's nothing to iterate, just access by key: `print(item_out_list['fvRsNodeAtt']['attributes']["descr"], item_out_list['fvRsNodeAtt']['attributes']["value"])`

Comment: because thats what it pulls from the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static = [item_all[item]['attributes']['descr'] + ', ' + item_all[item]['attributes']['value'] for item_all in item_out_list for item in item_all]

print (static)
```

output:
['apple, mango', 'peach, banana']

Comment: sorry I have slight modified the question because I realised the API is giving multiples, not sure if that changes your code ?

Comment: @Hooch_dgb, ok, I updated the code based on your new format

Comment: that works perfectly, could I trouble you to explain what the item_all and item is doing, just separate variables that its storing information and then looping over to give output

Comment: item_all is the first looping which get single dictionary from item_out_list, then looping it again and the first key in that dictionary will be a key to get data from item_all

Answer (score 0):

here is what you need

```
static = [list(item_out_list['fvRsNodeAtt']['attributes'].values())[2: 4]]
```

heres another way

```
static = [item_out_list['fvRsNodeAtt']['attributes']['descr'] + " " + item_out_list['fvRsNodeAtt']['attributes']['value']]
```

here how to get everything without looping

```
static = [item_out_list['fvRsNodeAtt']['attributes']]
```

Comment: so when I tried that, I get the following error

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: changed the code

Comment: thank you for your time.

still having the same issue on top two, perhaps its what the API is doing tho.


 static = [item_out_list['fvRsNodeAtt']['attributes']['descr'] + " " + item_out_list['fvRsNodeAtt']['attributes']['value']]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: replace item_out_list with just item

Comment: il try that thank you, 

sorry I have slight modified the question because I realised the API is giving multiples fvRsNodeAtt entires, not sure if that changes your code ?

Comment: it should not.
did the code work?